# PDF file upload only works in JCE (Joomla 3.10.6)

Tags: editor, file-upload

I'm puzzled by why I can only upload PDFs from within the editor when I use JCE. The site I'm working on is using YOOtheme Pro and if I try to add a PDF as a link in a gallery element it "silently fails".

I then checked uploading a PDF by going to **Joomla Admin > Control Panel > Media** and uploading a file and for PDFs I get:

> *Error: Invalid mime type detected*.

I disabled "Check MIME Types" in **Global Configuration > Media** and it still failed in **Control Panel > Media**.

If I disable "Restrict Uploads" as well then I can upload a PDF.

Our webhosts say that fileinfo.so is enabled.

What am I missing?!

Comment: is "pdf" and "PDF" set in your Legal Extensions field in the Media config?

Comment: Yes, they were there by default.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling "Check MIME Types", you should keep it enable and add "**pdf**" in "*Legal Extensions (File Types)*" field, and second, add "**application/pdf**" in the second "*Legal MIME Types*" field.

Comment: I added pdf and the mime type under the "Legal" section and now get:

**Error
Not a valid image.**

Comment: Sorry, I mean to add "pdf" into "Legal Extensions (File Types)" not "Legal Image Extensions".

Comment: Sorry, that's what I did. Apologies for any confusion.